# Integral representation of Dirac distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, discrete, dirac-delta-distributions

The Fourier transform of the Dirac distribution is given by

$$\tilde \delta(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2 \pi})^3} \int_{\Bbb R^3} \delta(\vec{r})e^{-i \vec{k} \vec{r}} d^3r = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2 \pi})^3}\tag{1}.$$

By transforming back again, we get an integral representation of the Dirac distribution, which is given by

$$\delta(\vec{r}) =  \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3} \int_{\Bbb R^3} e^{i \vec{k} \vec{r}} d^3k.\tag{2}$$

**My question:**

In some books (for example in the context of quantized modes $\vec{k}$ in a volume $V$), it reads

$$\delta(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{V} \int e^{i \vec{k} \vec{r}} d^3r,\tag{3}$$

with a finite volume $V$.

How can one justify this formula - why can one use a finite volume $V$ instead of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): In the context of quantized modes $\vec{k}$, the lhs. of eq. (3) should be the Kronecker delta $\delta_{\vec{k},\vec{0}},$ not the Dirac delta $\delta^3(\vec{k})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Kronecker delta is dimensionless, while the Dirac delta has the dimensions of one-over its argument:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{}[\delta_{a,b}]&=1\\
[\delta(a-b)]&=[a]^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

With this, you should be able to tell if $(3)$ is a Dirac delta or a Kronecker delta. Hint: it's a Kronecker delta in disguise - the integral denoting a sum:
$$
\frac 1V\int\mathrm d^3r\ f(r)=\sum_i f(r_i)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
But why doesn't the validity of equation $(3)$ depend on the volume $V$? Perhaps, I still don't see the point here.

Comment: @Peter123 note that the r.h.s. of (3) does **not** depend on $V$, and it is **not** an integral. It is a sum, so $\delta_k\sim \sum_j\ \mathrm e^{ikx_j}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties