# How can infinite sine waves localize to a single pulse in space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, interference, superposition

I have heard countless times (and not just when discussing the Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle) that making a short pulse using sine waves requires more and more sine waves to localize the pulse closer and closer, and for a pulse to be localized perfectly you would need infinite sine waves. Unfortunately, this explanation makes no *mathematical* sense to me.

Sine waves cycle infinitely, no matter the phase, amplitude, or frequency. So, how can they destructively interfere everywhere except at one location? If there is any location that doesn't destructively interfere, you should see infinite other locations where it also doesn't interfere, presumably at some set spacing, much more like a square wave for computer timing than a single pulse. The waves are infinite and unchanging throughout space; how can infinitely repeating waves all add up to produce something at only one location?

My only guess towards a plausible answer (as I've found no direct explanation of this, and in college they always used cyclic examples when discussing fourier transforms) has me simply limiting the extents of each sine wave such that you only get one localized pulse (instead of infinite). However, creating arbitrary constraints to make the math give you only a single pulse seems wholly inconsistent with the typical physics explanations provided.

Thank you for any guidance and understanding related to this topic.

---

I debated if this should be in the math stackexchange (as it's most directly related to fourier transforms), but because this comes up so often while discussing Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, and that is where I keep seeing it come up, I felt this was a more appropriate outlet for this question.

Comment: What is the problem when coming from the definition of a fourier series ? When taking the limit of a T-periodic function to infinity T -> infty, the function is no longer periodic.

Comment: I looked up the definition of the FT on wikipedia, as well as having already seen all the videos on it from 3B1B (my college notes were useless), but I still have no idea how an infinite sine wave can constructively interfere in only one location. Maybe if you had literally an infinite number of sine waves to slowly destructively interfere all peaks out to infinity; but that isn't what simple animations show. After only 3 waves being added together you already start to get a nice localized pulse, but this just makes absolutely no sense to my logical brain, as described further above.

Comment: I dug into this some more, and found the sinc(x) function. I believe this may be the answer to my question. Infinite sine waves CAN NOT make a rectangular pulse; however, when you Fourier Transform a rectangular pulse, the answer seems to be the sinc(x) = sin(x)/x function, not the sine function = sin(x).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fourier Transform of 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/161907/226902). See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/334096/226902

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of a rectangle is the sinc function. Since the Fourier transform is simply a superposition of different sine-waves (a cosine-wave is a sine-wave, which is shifted by $\pi/2$) this is an example of your problem.

Please go ahead an check out the derivate of the above mentioned Fourier transform.

Comment: And also check the limit where the rectangle has zero width but unit area.